# Get all parents in parent child hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I have the following data in my table

```
ID          NAME                           PARENTID    STATUS
----------- ------------------------------ ----------- ------
1           Folder A                       0           0
2           Folder B                       1           0
3           Folder C                       2           1
4           Folder D                       1           0
5           Folder E                       4           0
6           Folder G                       5           0
7           Folder H                       6           1
```

Above records are from table [@Temp].

```
[Name] - Folder Name
[ID] - Unique ID of folder in database (identity)
[ParentID] - Represents the parent of current folder.
```

Query to populate above data in the table:

```
  DECLARE @Temp TABLE
    (
      [ID] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      [NAME] VARCHAR(30) ,
      [PARENTID] INT,
      [STATUS] BIT
    )

  INSERT    INTO @Temp
            SELECT  'Folder A' ,
                    0, 0
            UNION
            SELECT  'Folder B' ,
                    1, 0
            UNION
            SELECT  'Folder C' ,
                    2, 1
            UNION
            SELECT  'Folder D' ,
                    1, 0
            UNION
            SELECT  'Folder E' ,
                    4, 0
            UNION
            SELECT  'Folder G' ,
                    5, 0
            UNION
            SELECT  'Folder H' ,
                    6, 1
```

I am having the following query to get records where status=1

```
  SELECT    *
  FROM      @Temp WHERE [STATUS]=1
```

which gives the following output

```
ID          NAME                           PARENTID    STATUS
----------- ------------------------------ ----------- ------
3           Folder C                       2           1
7           Folder H                       6           1
```

**My goal is to fetch those records too which are the parents (till parentid=0)** of the records came with the above query. i.e I want to get this output which contains the parents of Folder C and Folder H:

```
ID          NAME                           PARENTID    STATUS
----------- ------------------------------ ----------- ------
1           Folder A                       0           0
2           Folder B                       1           0
3           Folder C                       2           1
4           Folder D                       1           0
5           Folder E                       4           0
6           Folder G                       5           0
7           Folder H                       6           1
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected result where the expected result is not the same as the source data?

Answer (score 0):

```
  DECLARE @Temp TABLE
    (
      [ID] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      [NAME] VARCHAR(30) ,
      [PARENTID] INT ,
      [STATUS] BIT
    )

  INSERT    INTO @Temp
            SELECT  'Folder A' ,
                    0 ,
                    0
            UNION
            SELECT  'Folder B' ,
                    1 ,
                    0
            UNION
            SELECT  'Folder C' ,
                    2 ,
                    1
            UNION
            SELECT  'Folder D' ,
                    1 ,
                    0
            UNION
            SELECT  'Folder E' ,
                    4 ,
                    0
            UNION
            SELECT  'Folder G' ,
                    5 ,
                    1
            UNION
            SELECT  'Folder H' ,
                    6 ,
                    0                    


  CREATE  TABLE #TempTable
    (
      [RowIndex] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      [ID] INT ,
      [ParentID] INT
    )
  DECLARE @TempIds TABLE ( [ID] INT )               
  INSERT    INTO #TempTable
            ( [ID] ,
              [ParentID]
            )
            SELECT  [ID] ,
                    [ParentID]
            FROM    @Temp
            WHERE   [STATUS] = 1  



  DECLARE @intFlag INT
  DECLARE @Count INT
  SET @intFlag = 1
  SELECT    @Count = COUNT(1)
  FROM      @Temp
  WHILE ( @intFlag <= @Count )
    BEGIN
        PRINT @intFlag

        DECLARE @ID INT
        SELECT  @ID = [ParentID]
        FROM    #TempTable
        WHERE   RowIndex = @intFlag
        SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1;
        WITH    CTE
                  AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                                ParentID
                       FROM     @Temp
                       WHERE    ID = @ID
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT   MainTbl.ID ,
                                MainTbl.ParentID
                       FROM     @Temp MainTbl
                                INNER JOIN cte ON MainTbl.ID = cte.ParentID
                     )
            INSERT  INTO @TempIds
                    SELECT  ID
                    FROM    CTE  


    END



  ;WITH  cte
          AS ( SELECT    DISTINCT
                        ID
               FROM     @TempIds
             )
    SELECT  T.*
    FROM    cte
            INNER JOIN @Temp T ON [T].ID = cte.ID
    UNION
    SELECT  T1.*
    FROM    #TempTable TempTable
            INNER JOIN @Temp T1 ON [TempTable].ID = T1.ID

  DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Output:

```
ID          NAME                           PARENTID    STATUS
----------- ------------------------------ ----------- ------
1           Folder A                       0           0
2           Folder B                       1           0
3           Folder C                       2           1
4           Folder D                       1           0
5           Folder E                       4           0
6           Folder G                       5           1
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a recursive CTE - I start with the bottom, any folder that does not have a child. From there, I pass up whether or not a '1' Status was encountered in the 'GOOD' column, and the distinct clears out the duplicates created by starting at the bottom.

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT ID, NAME, PARENTID, STATUS GOOD, STATUS
    FROM @Temp T1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Temp T2 WHERE T2.PARENTID = T1.ID)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT T.ID, T.NAME, T.PARENTID, T.STATUS | C.GOOD GOOD, T.STATUS
    FROM @Temp T
    JOIN CTE C
    ON C.PARENTID = T.ID
)

SELECT DISTINCT ID, NAME, PARENTID, STATUS FROM CTE
WHERE GOOD = 1
ORDER BY ID ASC
```